# jquery sliding bar under nav with fixed positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi Guys im having a problem with the slider bar under my menu im new to jquery and css.

My first issue is when the page loads the bar does not load under the menu until you mouse over it load on the side of the page

The second issue is that if i scroll out **zoom out** the bar disappears over to the side so here is the basic html css and jquery.. really stuck with this hope someone can help

My first post here i i did it correctly... need help first the css

```
#topnav { position: relative; width: 997px; height: 50px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/navbg.png) no-repeat; }
                    #navbar { width: 997px; height: 38px; }             
                    #slider-container {  height: 16px; width: 997px; position: relative;}
        #menu-slide {
        height: 16px;
        width: 64px;
        background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/glowbg.png);
        font-size: 1px;
        line-height: 1px;
        z-index: -5;
        position: fixed;
        top: 180px;
        left: 20px;
        }
```

Now the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slideshow').cycle({
                fx:      'scrollHorz',
                timeout:  0,
                prev:    '#prev',
                next:    '#next'
            }); 
         $('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
         autoArrows:  false
         });
         $("#background_image").fullBg();

        $('li').mouseover( function() { 
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            //var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5;
            var left = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2 - 20);
            $('#menu-slide').stop().animate( {left: left  }, 400 );
        });
        $('li').mouseleave(function(){
             var left = $('.first').offset().left + ($('.first').width() / 2 - 20);
             $('#menu-slide').stop().animate( {left: left  }, 400 );
        });
     });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function pageLoad() { 
        var left = $('.first').offset().left + ($('.first').width() / 2);
            $('#menu-slide').stop().animate( {left: left  }, 400 );
      } 
    </script>
```

> now the html

```
<div id="topnav">                    
                        <ul id="navbar"class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="current first"><a href="#a">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">CORPORATE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CRUSING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LEISURE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">GROUPS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">VIRTUOSO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
                            <li class="last"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                            <div id="slider-container">
                                <div id="menu-slide"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```